# SQL grammar for insert record and ignore exists with index instead of primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with structure: `id(INT, PK), entryid(INT), date(INT), region(CHAR), location(ENUM), views(INT)`. All fields except id are non-unique.

How do I insert a record, so that if there is same `entryid,date,region,location`, then ignore, otherwise insert to table?

BTW, I am using mysql.

Comment: I assume that you don't have (entryid,date,region,location) declared as unique, in which case such an insert would fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a special version of the insert statement in mysql for this:

```
INSERT INTO table
VALUES (...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entryid = ?, etc -- this modifier will do the trick
```

Consult [the mysql manual entry for this syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for a full explanation

#### Edit:

This behaviour works on the *primary key* being identical. To make it work on multiple columns, you need a multi-column primary key, which you would define for your table like this:

```
create table mytable (
    entryid int,
    date int,
    region char,
    location enum ('a', 'b', 'c'),
    views int,
    primary key (entryid, date, region, location) -- list your key field like this
);
```

Comment: How do I set (entryid,date,region,location) together as unique?

Comment: It works when I set (entryid,date,region,location) together as UNIQUE instead fo INDEX.